# How to make text-to-speech speak in both of my languages?

Tags: windows-10, text-to-speech, narrator

I use Microsoft Narrator because I'm vision impaired.

I've configured it to speak with the voice "Microsoft Mark - English" but I have also installed "Microsoft Ivan - Bulgarian". **When I type bulgarian (cyrillic) text** into the Google Chrome address bar, **I don't hear my words/letters/symbols echoed to me**. With latin text it works fine.

The same problem exists in most of Windows. For example, in Notepad, Wordpad, MS Word 2016.

Well, at least in MS Word when I move the text cursor into a cyrillic word, the word gets read correctly. But this doesn't happen in the rest of my Windows apps.

Can I make it work in more (or all) apps in Windows?